# Extracting subset of data.table based on date around a given day of the year

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data table like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(3)
test <- data.table(date=as.Date(Sys.time())+runif(1000,1,365))
test[, year := as.integer(format(date, "%Y"))]
test
```

I need to subset it based on today's date, but seems like I am making a mistake here:

```
test[date %in% (as.Date(paste(year,"-06-04",sep="")) + (-3:3)),]

test[date %in% (as.Date(paste(as.integer(format(date, "%Y")),"-06-04",sep="")) + (-3:3)),]
```

The following command works, but gives me a warning:

```
test[as.character(date) %in% as.character(as.Date(paste(year,"-06-04",sep="")) + (-3:3)),]
```

Any ideas??

Comment: FYI, `data.table` has its own date manipulation functions and you could create your `year` variable by just doing `test[, year := year(date)]`

Comment: Yeah..you might want to look into ```as.IDate``` and then you could use the ```between``` function

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg and @Mike.Gahan! It would be nice to have a complete list of all the functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has [asked for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047683/extracting-subset-of-data-table-based-on-date-around-a-given-day-of-the-year#comment37087710_24048163) why two of his approaches "do not work" and why the third one gives a warning.

To my surprise, the answers were harder to find than I had expected and the investigation has given me some new insights.

#### Issues to investigate

To be more precise, *all three* approaches produce the same warning message:

> In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Furthermore, the first two approaches do *not* run into an error condition but return just an

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: date,year

#### Explanation of the warning message

In all three approaches, the OP creates the RHS of the `%in%` operator by combining a vector of length 1000, e.g., `as.Date(paste(year,"-06-04",sep=""))` with a vector of length 7 (`-3:3`). In R, the shorter vector is recycled as necessary (with a warning when they are recycled only *fractionally*), see `help("Arithmetic")`.

This can be demonstrated with a simple example

```
1:10 + (-3:3)
```

> ```
> [1] -2  0  2  4  6  8 10  5  7  9
>
> Warning message:
> In 1:10 + (-3:3) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

Most likely, above result is not what the OP had in mind. I suppose he wants to combine each element of the first vector with each element of the second vector. This can be achieved by the `outer()` function or using `expand.grid()` or `data.table`'s cross join `CJ()`:

```
outer(1:10, -3:3, "+")
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
>  [1,]   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4
>  [2,]   -1    0    1    2    3    4    5
>  [3,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
>  [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
>  [5,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
>  [6,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
>  [7,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
>  [8,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
>  [9,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
> [10,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
> ```

```
CJ(1:10, -3:3)[, V3 := V1 + V2][]
```

> ```
>     V1 V2 V3
>  1:  1 -3 -2
>  2:  1 -2 -1
>  3:  1 -1  0
>  4:  1  0  1
>  5:  1  1  2
>  ---
> 66: 10 -1  9
> 67: 10  0 10
> 68: 10  1 11
> 69: 10  2 12
> 70: 10  3 13
>     V1 V2 V3
> ```

#### Fractional `Date`

The second issue was much harder to track down. It is caused by the way the OP creates the sample data:

```
test <- data.table(date=as.Date(Sys.time())+runif(1000,1,365))
```

`runif(1000,1,365)` creates a vector of `double`, *non-integerish* values:

```
set.seed(3); head(runif(1000,1,365))
```

> ```
> [1]  62.16712 294.93597 141.11902 120.29529 220.16465 220.99944
> ```

These are added to a `Date` value which creates *fractional dates*. The fractional part is invisible when printed:

```
as.Date("2018-01-01") + c(0, 0.1)
```

> ```
> [1] "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01"
> ```

It only becomes apparent when the dates are converted to `numeric` or `POSIXct`:

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date("2018-01-01") + c(0, 0.1))
```

> ```
> [1] "2018-01-01 01:00:00 CET" "2018-01-01 03:23:59 CET"
> ```

Now, it is obvious why the condition in

```
test[date %in% (as.Date(paste(year,"-06-04",sep="")) + (-3:3)),]
```

never found a match. The LHS `date` always has a fractional part while the RHS has `integerish` values without a fractional part. The root cause is that `Date` is constructed using `double`. Note that the `data.table` package introduced the integer based date class `IDate`.

There is a simple fix to OP's code used to create the sample data:

```
set.seed(3)
test <- data.table(date = as.Date(Sys.time()) + as.integer(runif(1000,1,365)))
```

Alternatively, `Sys.Date()` and `sample.int()` can be used:

```
set.seed(3)
test1 <- data.table(date = Sys.Date() + sample.int(365, 1000, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I completely understand the question...but is this of help?  It looks like you want all observations within 3 days of today's date regardless of year?

```
test <- data.table(date=as.IDate(Sys.time())+runif(1000,1,365))
test[month(date)==6 & abs(mday(date)-4)<=3]
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but I am still not able to understand why my code is not working!!